# Implementing a multicolumn layout with independant row heights

Tags: css, html, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a layout similar to what the new Google+ layout and similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084507/implementing-a-multicolumn-listview-with-independant-row-heights) (but using html).

Currently Google+ uses 1 div for each column. I am trying to see if there would be another way to do this.

Possibly the flexbox model of CSS3 would help but the compatibility level of it is ... meh.

I tried the inline-block model but going this way create rows that are not independent on each other's height.

There are existing solutions, but everything requires IE10+ or IE11+. I would need a solution that is IE7+ compatible. I don't see anything beside the div per column.

Has anybody had the occasion of doing something similar?

Comment: do you mean something like this: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol/

Comment: @blackbee yes, that represents more what I'm trying to do. But it's not IE7 compatible.

Comment: If you have specific requirements, they need to be in the question.  There's nothing you can do for a browser that old and broken unless you're open to using JavaScript.

Comment: @cimmanon point taken, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS multi-column layout module can do what you're looking for.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/CcGlE

```
.foo {
    columns: 30em; /* desired number of columns and/or width of column */
}
```

Prefixes may be necessary.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn